# Is shared memory for fork shared if the program is run from two terminals in linux

Tags: c++, linux, fork, share, mmap

If in my c++ code, I use mmap() to share a global variable, and i run one version of the program from the linux terminal, and in the same machine, I open another terminal, and run the same program, will these two programs access the same memory which is shared?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use `mmap`. If both programs create a shared mapping of the same file (or shared memory node or whatever), yes. If they map different files, or create private or anonymous mappings, no (although a private mapping will use copy-on-write, so the memory is shared until either process writes to it).

Answer (score 1):

Two processes will see the same contents of a memory mapped region only if

- the same file is mapped in both processes
- the mapping in both processes is done with the `MAP_SHARED` flag.

If doing an anonymous file mapping, there's no backing file and hence the processes will not see each other contents. To implement shared memory you can either create a file in a `tmpfs` mount (usually `/dev/shm` is available for that). Or, on Linux, given a recent enough kernel (Linux 3.17 or later) the syscall [`memfd_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) can be used to create a `tmpfs` file without a filesystem entry in one process and to share with other processes can use [*file descriptor passing*](http://keithp.com/blogs/fd-passing/) to give them access to that file.